# mongoid how to get all documents in a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I know my question is rather silly but I have looked in mongoid tutorial and on SO trying to figure out how to get all documents in a collection with mongoid, that is the counterpart of db.collection.find() in mongo shell.

Many SO questions ask for some criteria , I just want to get all of them, no not the embedded documents, just the same result of db.collection.find() but from mongoid.

I need this because in my mailer preview I want to get all users to see the emails sent to them and confirm their accounts, I'm using devise here with Rails 4.2.5 and mongoid 5.

I tried Model.find and Model.find_by and Model.pluck, the first one returns nil, the second returns only one document(because I get undefined method each for <#Model...>) and the last one would only return the values of one key.

So how to do this ?

### Edit

here is my model:

```
class Researcher 

include Mongoid::Document
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :validatable,:confirmable,:recoverable,:omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:gplus]
  #, :rememberable, :trackable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time,localize: true

  ## Rememberable
  #field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  #field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  #field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  #field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  #field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  #field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  ## Confirmable
  field :confirmation_token,   type: String
  field :confirmed_at,         type: Time,localize: true
  field :confirmation_sent_at, type: Time,localize: true
  field :unconfirmed_email,    type: String # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # field :failed_attempts, type: Integer, default: 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # field :unlock_token,    type: String # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # field :locked_at,       type: Time
  field :username, type: String
  field :provider,type: String
  field :uid,type: String

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |researcher|
      if data = session["devise.gplus"] && session["devise.gplus"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        researcher.email = data["email"] if researcher.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |researcher|
    researcher.email = auth.info.email
    researcher.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]       
  end
end
end
```

and this is my mailer preview:

```
class ResearchersMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview 
  def initialize
    @vals=Researcher.all
  end
  def confirmation_instructions    
    @vals.each do |val|    
      ResearchersMailer.confirmation_instructions(val,val.confirmation_token , {})
    end
  end
  def reset_password_instructions
    @vals.each do |val|          
      ResearchersMailer.reset_password_instructions(val, val.reset_password_token, {})    
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @muistooshort I updated my question

Comment: What does `Researcher.all` do for you? Does that end up complaining about `find_first_mime_type`? Are you sure the problem is with `Researcher.all` rather than the return value from one of your `ResearcherMailerPreview` methods? Sounds like you're handing `@vals` to something inside ActionMailer that is expecting a mail object of some kind.

Comment: @muistooshort yes I get find_first_mime_type, I'm not passing `@vals` to any kind of ActionMailer, it's just for preview.

Comment: But your `confirmation_instructions` and `reset_password_instructions` methods *return* `@vals` and `@vals` will be a `Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo` instance. There should be a stack trace to go with the `find_first_mime_type` exception.

Comment: @muistooshort ahhh I thought each returns nil, Now I know it returns the array on which it was called.  
Thanks, I think I'm going to fix it later and post the answer myself

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is:

`Model.all`

Then you can get each of them by looping over your collection.

Comment: I get "undefined method `find_first_mime_type' for #<Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo:0x007f2bccec0258>"

Answer (score 0):

`Model.all`

Returns all documents *if* your selector is empty.
In order to get access to all entries while you are already preselected, use:

`Model.unscoped.all`